# LINQ How to select more than 1 property in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-types

We often use the following lambda expression

```
MyList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Is possible to get more than 1 property usinglambda expression ? E.g `Id` and `Name` from MyList?

I know that I can use the following syntax:

```
(from item in MyList
 select new { item.Id, item.Name }).ToList();
```

Can I do the same thing using lambda expression?

Comment: actually this is lambda expression: `new { item.Id, item.Name }`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
MyList.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm, but as what then cast that list from the Object bag, e.g Session ?

Comment: @Tony, in this case, the `Select` is returning an anonymous type, just as in the case of the query expression version. If you need to stuff the result away and reuse it later or pass it around, then you should go ahead and define a concrete type in your code.

Comment: @Tony, once that type has been defined, all you need to do is alter the select to be `Select(x => new YourNewType { x.Id, x.Name })`

Comment: @Anthony Unfortunately to do that with a named type you need to sacrifice immutability.

Comment: To address @CodeInChaos' point, if immutability is a concern, simply pass the parameters in via a proper constructor. `Select(x => new YourNewType(x.Id, x.Name))` And then, of course, define the properties/fields of the class such that the object is immutable post-construction.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, @Anthony: Or use one of the `Tuple<>` types if you're on .NET4.

Comment: Well, then how to pass different model which is made for only passing data as a custom model. The model is predefined like public class`APIDepartment
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentTitle { get; set; }
        IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; } 
    }` how can i send through this model ? I'm failed badly, using lambda expression. I have tried `IEnumerable<APIDepartment> employees=_db.Departments.Where(d=> d.DepartmentTitle.Contains(partialDept)).Select(x=>new APIDepartment(){x.DepartmentTitle, x.DepartmentID}).AsEnumerable();`

Answer (score 3):

The feature you're interested in is C# 3's [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

You can create a new instance of an anonymous type with:

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello", this.Text };
```

Of course this works as a lamda too:

```
SomeThing.Select( () => new {X=1,Y=2} )
```

anywhere in your code. It also picks up property names, in which case you don't need to specify it explicitly(the third member of the anonymous type in my example is automatically named `Text`.

Unfortunately you can't use them as a non generic return-type of a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sample = dbcontext.MyList
                      .Select(m => new Mylist{ sampleid=m.sampleid,item=m.item })
                      .ToList();
```