# How do you databind entities to WebForm controls with dot syntax?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding

We have worked out how to databind entites with "sql like" syntax:

```
var countryQuery = from c in ShopEntities.ShippingCountries
                   orderby c.Order
                   select new { c.ShippingCountryId, c.Name};

Country.DataValueField = "ShippingCountryId"; //country is a DropDownList
Country.DataTextField = "Name";
Country.DataSource = countryQuery;
DataBind();
```

But how do you do the above with the "dot" syntax

```
var countryQuery = ShopEntities.ShippingCountries.OrderBy(s => s.Order).what to put here????

Country.DataValueField = "ShippingCountryId";
Country.DataTextField = "Name";
Country.DataSource = countryQuery;
DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [LINQ How to select more than 1 property in a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346431/linq-how-to-select-more-than-1-property-in-the-lambda-expression)

Basically just:

```
.Select(c => new { c.ShippingCountryId, c.Name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you did for orderBy

```
ar countryQuery = ShopEntities.ShippingCountries.OrderBy(s => s.Order).Select(s => new classref {ShippingCountryId = s.ShippingCountryId,Name = s.Name})
```

ot this one

```
ar countryQuery = ShopEntities.ShippingCountries.OrderBy(s => s.Order).Select(s => new { s.ShippingCountryId, s.Name})
```